# Unresolved reference when importing in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, python-import, setup.py

I've installed a Python package from GitHub using Pip. It installed it to a src folder inside my package. My foldr structure now looks like this:

```
TestApiClient/src/sdk-config/config_a
```

I need to import `ConfigurationApi` and `Manager`.

I tried this but it doesn't work:

```
from src.config_a.configuration_api import ConfigurationApi
from src.config_a.manager import Manager
```

How should this be imported?

**ConfigurationApi setup.py**

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import os
import re
import sys

from setuptools import setup, find_packages

# Config sdk python version check
_valid  =  sys.version_info[:2] == (2, 7) or sys.version_info >= (3,4)
if not _valid:
    sys.exit("Sorry, SDK only supports versions 2.7, 3.4, 3.5, 3.6, 3.7 of python.")


ROOT = os.path.dirname(__file__)
VERSION_RE = re.compile(r'''__version__ = ['"]([a-z0-9.]+)['"]''')


def get_version():
    init = open(os.path.join(ROOT, 'config', '__init__.py')).read()
    return VERSION_RE.search(init).group(1)


setup(
    name='sdk-config',
    version=get_version(),
    description='Config SDK for Python',
    long_description=open('README.md').read(),
    author='ME',
    url='https://github.my_company.com/my_org/repo_name',
    scripts=[],
    packages=find_packages(exclude=['tests*']),
    include_package_data=True,
    license="Apache License 2.0",
    classifiers=[
        'Development Status :: 5 - Production/Stable',
        'Intended Audience :: Developers',
        'Natural Language :: English',
        'License :: OSI Approved :: Apache Software License',
        'Programming Language :: Python',
        'Programming Language :: Python :: 2.7',
        'Programming Language :: Python :: 3',
        'Programming Language :: Python :: 3.4',
        'Programming Language :: Python :: 3.5',
        'Programming Language :: Python :: 3.6',
        'Programming Language :: Python :: 3.7',
    ],
)
```

**Additional Information**

I uninstalled and reinstalled but this time I didn't install in editable mode.

If I do `pip list` I can see that `sdk-config` is installed. I tried to import that with `sdk_config = __import__("sdk-config")` thinking I could maybe do something like:

```
from sdk_config.config_a.configuration_api import ConfigurationApi
from sdk_config.config_a.manager import Manager
```

However, that resulted in this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/me/PycharmProjects/TestConfigApiClient/TestApiClient.py", line 1, in <module>
    sdk_config = __import__("sdk-config")
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sdk-config'
```

Comment: How did you actually install it? `pip` doesn't "install things into src folders inside packages", really. Also, if the package is publicly on GitHub, please link to it too – no need to withhold detail from us!

Comment: `pip install -e git+ssh://git@github.my_company.com/my_org/repo_name.git@prototype#egg=config_sdk`

Comment: Right – that installs the package(s) into your virtualenv or other Python path directory (e.g. `.local`) depending on configuration. Sure, the actual code will live in a `src` directory _somewhere_, but you're still supposed to just import it by the package name alone.

Comment: So are you saying I should use:

`import ConfigurationApi`
`import Manager`

I tried that without any success.

Comment: If there is a ConfigurationApi package. Without knowing how the repo and setup.py is set up, it's hard to know more precisely.

Comment: I've added the setup.py to the question

Comment: Right. Since there's `find_packages(exclude=['tests*'])`, the packages installed will be the folders in the root of the repo. Guessing from the code in `get_version()`, there's a package called `config`. So maybe `config.config_a.manager`. But really, since this is apparently a company-internal package, you should ask within your company.

Comment: No, it's something I'm attempting myself. For now I assume I've done something wrong with the setup.py. I'll have a look there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem seems to be that I installed the package globally but I was working in a virtual environment which didn't have the package. When I then installed it in the virtual environment it worked.